# Octave package install error due to libncurses5-dev

Tags: apt, dependencies, 21.04, octave

I've installed Octave on Ubuntu 21.04 but run into problems installing packages. After trying to install liboctave-dev, I get

> liboctave-dev depends on libncurses5-dev; however:
> Package libncurses5-dev is not installed.
>
> dpkg: error processing package liboctave-dev (--configure):
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

then ..

> Failed to fetch
> http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/ncurses/libncurses-dev_6.2+20201114-2build1_amd64.deb
> 403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

I've tried apt update and --fix-broken install. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "au mirror" http://mirror.pacific.net.au/linux/ubuntu/pool/main/n/ncurses/libncurses-dev_6.2+20201114-2build1_amd64.deb for libncurses-dev is down too. http://ftp.iinet.net.au , nz mirrors, European and some US mirrors are OK.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Yes @NOrbert - problem solved just by changing the Ubuntu Software server.  I should have looked more closely at the "failed to fetch" message!